Risks of Visa Violations Being Discovered in Court?
Curious to know what happens when a state court discovers any sort of visa violations which fall within federal/immigration court's jurisdiction. Examples could be that someone is working illegally on non-work visa (B/F class visa), or could be that someone has overstayed their visa, failure to report address change, or any such visa violations. In such cases are state courts required to report them to immigration authorities? Or would state courts not really care since it's not within the state jurisdiction?
What about lawyers, if either side discovers this, do they have any ethical or legal obligation to report them?
For the purpose of this discussion, assume no attorney-client privilege exists because it either pertains to either a witnesses in a trial or it was discovered by the opposing counsel, and also assume that no criminal laws were broken.

Immigration is a charged issue in the USA right now. I don't know the obligations of the courts in Missouri, but I do know that various locales have tried to pass laws both forbidding and requiring local law enforcement to enforce federal immigration law. I suspect that this is still mostly up in the air. Pragmatically though, there is nothing that prevents courtroom staff or law enforcement from "dropping a dime" to INS if they think they are seeing an immigration violation and they care enough. Whether that would be enough to spur INS into action is also a question.

@CharlesE.Grant I think enforcing immigration laws is not an option for local law enforcement (there famously was an Arizona sheriff pardoned by Trump from going to prison after being convicted for trying that). What the localities are trying to encourage or forbid is providing support to ICE, not replacing them. Also, there hasn't been an INS for the last >20 years, it's time to retire that acronym.

I don't think there's any federal law requiring or prohibiting states from reporting immigration and visa violations. It's up to each state how they choose to work with ICE.

Another thing to consider: a lawyer who learns of the witness's immigration status and who knows that the employment was not authorized by that status could manipulate the witness to  he possibility that anyone who learns of the witness's immigration status, and therefore of the violation, might use that knowledge to influence the witness's testimony.

ICE has (or has had in the recent past) a policy of not detaining people in these circumstances, but it is only an internal policy and isn't a defense to deportation if it isn't followed.

A was robbed by B at gunpoint, C witnessed it. All three meet in court. How would the judge find out about their immigration status, since it's quite irrelvant to the case? And as phoog side, it would be very very bad if the witness C could be blackmailed (or A, who is presumably also a witness).
